# One tap not dismissing on authenticating with button

Tags: google-chrome, google-signin, google-one-tap, fedcm

I am currently migrating GSI to FedCM following this guide https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/fedcm-migration.

My use case shows both one tap and a Sign In With Google [button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.renderButton) on the same page. When `use_fedcm_for_prompt` is true and I authenticate with the button, one tap doesn't seem to dismiss itself. It requires a fresh page reload to dismiss. Without FedCM, when I authenticate with the button, one tap always dismissed with the old experience.

I initialized google identity by:

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: 'MOCK_CLIENT_ID',
  auto_select: true,
  cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
  callback: () => {
    // Perform auth
  },
  prompt_parent_id: 'MOCK_PARENT_ID',
  itp_support: true,
  use_fedcm_for_prompt: true
});

// Show one tap
google.accounts.id.prompt();

// Render Google button
// buttonElement is the HTML element of the parent rendering the Google button
google.accounts.id.renderButton(buttonElement, {
  theme: 'outline',
  size: 'large',
  logo_alignment: 'left',
  locale: 'en_US',
  text: 'continue_with',
  width: '400',
});
```

I've tried to manually dismiss one tap with `google.accounts.id.cancel()` through callbacks and click listeners on the button, but when FedCM is enabled `google.accounts.id.cancel()` doesn't dismiss the prompt anymore.

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(buttonElement, {
  theme: 'outline',
  size: 'large',
  logo_alignment: 'left',
  locale: 'en_US',
  text: 'continue_with',
  width: '400',
  click_listener: () => {
    google.accounts.id.cancel()
  },
});
```

Is there any work around to this to make sure one tap dismisses itself when I authenticate with the button? I shouldn't need to manually dismiss one tap after it authenticates with either the button or one tap.

Comment: Hi, Could you provide some sample code on how you called google.accounts.id.cancel(). I just tried it with FedCM enabled. The google.accounts.id.cancel() method successfully dismissed the prompt.

Comment: @hermz I updated my description to include some code snippets
`google.accounts.id.cancel()` doesn't seem to work for me when `use_fedcm_for_prompt` is `true`. I also shouldn't need to dismiss the prompt manually. When I authenticate with the button and Google's prompt shows up, one tap should auto dismiss (this is the behavior when `use_fedcm_for_prompt` is false)

Comment: thanks for the updates. I tried the code snippets you posted. With `use_fedcm_for_prompt` set to `true`, I used the combination of `google.accounts.id.cancel()` and `click_listener`. I was able to dismiss the One Tap prompt when I clicked on the button.